# Mule data mapping date time conversion not showing hours

Tags: datetime, mule, datamapper, date-conversion

I have a date value of 2016-04-06-06:00 coming from one system and I need to map it to a string field.

I'm trying to use `output.DateStr = date2str(input.myDate,"yyyy-MM-dd-hh:mm");` in the data mapping script but the DateStr field shows 2016-04-06-12:00

I have also tried `"yyyy-MM-dd-HH:mm"` but this comes through as 2016-04-06-00:00

Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Answer (score 0):

try somtehing like :

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-/dd-HH:mm");

//DateFormat format method create a string 

String reportDate = df.format(yourDate);
```

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#[dateString = new java.util.Date().toString();
  payload = new org.mule.el.datetime.DateTime(dateString, 'yyyy-MM-dd-hh:mm');]
```

change dateString as '2016-04-06-06:00'.